# Scope in jQuery functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am confused why in the code below the first console.log shows me the object, yet the second is undefined. How do I fix this problem?

```
var listOfTweets = [];

for(var k = 0; k < search.length; k++){
    $.getJSON(searchURL, function(tweets){                              
        listOfTweets[k] = tweets;
        console.log(listOfTweets[k]);                               
    });
    console.log(listOfTweets[k]);
}
```

Comment: did you also notice that `k` has the same value in all the callback functions

Comment: Yes, this is just to demonstrate how I cannot access the same data inside the .getJSON.

Comment: Scope has nothing to do with jQuery

Comment: there's no such thing as jQuery functions. jQuery is a JavaScript function not a language with it's own constructs it's just clever JS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The getJSON is executed asyncronous and the last console.log is there for executed before the assignment

Since I don't know what you actually want is hard to tell you what you should do. What you need to keep in mind is the execution order.

In this code

```
 $.getJSON(searchURL, function(tweets){
          console.log("done");
    });
    console.log("Request send");
```

the first thing that happens is a request being send to `searchURL` then next thing is that "Request send" will be printed to the console and when the browser receives the response to the request then and no sooner will the function be called and "done" will be printed to the console

further your code has a problem with closure since k is closed over and will have the same value for all invocations of the call back (1)

to get around that problem you could use a self executing function

```
for(var k = 0;k<10;k++){
    $.getJSON(searchURL, (function(i){
          return function(tweets){  
                         console.log("done for " + i);
                 }
     }(k));
    console.log("Request send for " + k);
 }
```

notice that k is used as an argument for a function immediatedly, the value of the argument is stored for reference by the function return as the callback and will not change when k is incremented. If you do as you have done then since all callbacks are referencing the same object they will all also have the same value for k

(1) unless some returns before the looping ends

Answer (score 3):

All of the $.getJSON calls are happening asynchronously.  You're last "console.log" is likely being called "before" any of the getJSON calls are even done.

Answer (score 1):

Try saving k as follows:

```
var listOfTweets = [];

for(var k = 0; k < search.length; k++){
    $.getJSON(searchURL, function(tweets){    
        var kk = k; // saved!!                          
        listOfTweets[kk] = tweets;
        console.log(listOfTweets[kk]);                               
    });
    console.log(listOfTweets[k]);
}
```

Therefore when `k` is incremented it won't effect the `kk` that you saved

Comment: ...only that saving k in the callback function has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a closure to save the current value of `k` to the callback's scope. Else, `k` is equal to `search.length` after the loop when the callbacks are executed. Also, see [Javascript Callback Timing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10808586/1048572) for when you will be able to use a filled `listOfTweets`.

```
var listOfTweets = [];
var search = [url1, url2, ...];

$.each(search, function(k, searchURL) {
    $.getJSON(searchURL, function(tweets){                              
        console.log(listOfTweets[k] = tweets);         
    });
});

// After all the ajax request completed, you will be able to
console.log(listOfTweets);
```